# Can I return typed objects from a Dictionary<String,AnyObject>?

Tags: swift, types

Here's what I have right now:

```
enum TestKeys: String {
    case login = "login"
    case username = "username"
}

var testData: Dictionary<String,AnyObject>  = // a dictionary of known key/values

// I want the return value from this function to be typed
func getTestObject(key: TestKeys) -> AnyObject! {
    if let obj: AnyObject = testData[key.rawValue] {
        return obj
    } else {
        assertionFailure("We cannot find \(key.rawValue) in our testData")
        return nil
    }
}
```

I know in advance the keys and specific value types in my dictionary. What I'd like to be able to do is associate a type with each key, so that I can have typed return values when I access the content of the dictionary.

Comment: "associate a type with each key" When? Before you write `getTestObject` or after?

Comment: Before. I'd like to be able to fetch any object from my dictionary and have my fetching function return the correct type, not `AnyObject`.

Comment: So you can say something like `getTestString(key)` or `getTestInt(key)` because your code knows beforehand which type it's going to be, right?

Comment: I'd like to have the type tied to the enum, so that there is  a single method that will return a different type based on the enum you pass in.

Comment: Also, I have no idea if enums are a good way to do this. There may be another construct that will work.

Comment: This would require [dependent types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type) which I don't think you can get in Swift. You can try a generic function like `getTestObject<Int>(key: TestKeys)`.